# inner join equivalent for arrays

Tags: php, arrays

Is there an inner join equivalent for keys in arrays of data?  Here are the arrays:
[image]

The goal is to return an array that contains only the keys that are common between both arrays.  So these would be included in the result: propertyID, address, city, state, price, units, listed, taxes, taxyear, lastbuyer, lastpurchased, lastprice, comments.  However, inserted (which appears only in array 1) and Submission (which appears only in array 2) would not be part of the result.

Comment: Hmm, [`array_intersect_key()`](http://php.net/array_intersect_key) comes to mind.

Comment: @Jack - Made an error the first time I tried it.  After fixing the user error that worked as desired - thanks.

Comment: @knot22 it depends on which array you pass as the first argument; also, it would help if you posted the `var_export()` output of your variables, it makes it easier to provide a verifiable answer.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you want the final array to look like?

Answer (score 1):

With many thanks to Jack here is the solution...  
Assume the first array in the original question is $x and the second is $values.

```
$z = array_intersect_key($x, $values);
echo '<pre>' . print_r($z,1) . '</pre>';
```

[image]